# Problem on capacitors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, capacitance

Consider a two plate capacitor, with a voltage across them equal to *V*, that is placed inside a metal box (it is the same as adding another metal plate on each side of a capacitor and connecting them with a wire), such that the distance between any two adjacent plates is *d*. Now, one plate of the capacitor is connected to the additional plates via a wire. I am asked to find the new capacitance of this capacitor and the charge density on each plate. For this I assumed that the potential on three of the four plates is the same and I expressed them, as well as the potential difference between the plates in terms of the charge densities. I also assumed that the sum of the charge densities of all plates is zero. Is my reasoning correct? The charges on the plates of the capacitor end up being different an I am not sure if the definition of capacitance applies here